# How to search available commands in bash

Tags: bash, shell

So I can enter `systemc` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and get `systemctl`.

But what if I want to list all commands that end in `ctl`?

How would I do that?

Answer (score 12):

To list all available commands, including aliases, functions, bash builtins and bash keywords, use `compgen -c`. You may `grep` the resulting list with any pattern, for example:

```
compgen -c | grep 'ctl$'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use `apropos ctl | less` you will see all of the commands containing the string ctl which include man pages. It will also display a few others containing that string but there is surprisingly few of these unintended results so you may find it quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you searching the `$PATH` for matching files

```
( IFS=:; for p in $PATH; do ls -d "$p"/*ctl; done ) 2>/dev/null
```

I've used a subshell `( ... )` because I'm changing the shell variable `IFS`. An alternative would be to save it at the beginning (`OIFS="$IFS" IFS=:`) and restore it afterwards (`IFS="$OIFS"`) but to me this feels slightly less robust.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `find` :

```
( IFS=:; for dir in $PATH; do find $dir/ -type f -executable -iregex ".*ctl"; done )
```

To show cmd's only:

```
( IFS=:; for dir in $PATH; do find $dir/ -type f -executable -iregex ".*ctl" -printf '%f\n'; done ) 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This offers no benefits over @roaima's solution and has a serious drawback.

The purpose of find is to find files in a directory hierarchy, i.e. to search subdirectories as well as the cwd.

PATH searching does not do this. It only uses matching commands in the directories explicitly listed in $PATH, not in their subdirectories.
If a directory in $PATH has subdirectories (e.g. many accounts have ":.:" in their $PATH), find is going to consume time & IO by needlessly searching those too, even though they don't contribute to the list of available commands.